# How to write GWT wrappers to invoke MxGraph functions?

Tags: gwt, mxgraph

I want to introduce workflow in my application. 
I went through the screenshots of features supported by mxGraph and that is what I am looking for. 
My application UI is developed using GWT 2.0.4. Could anyone suggest how do I implement the workflow with MxGraph ?
I am new to MxGraph and went through few tutorials. 
Any sample code would help me in learning. It would be great if someone suggests how to write GWT wrappers and invoke the MxGraph functions.

Answer (score 0):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/davidjgraph/8019191) is an example of a GWT wrapper to the mxGraph class.